# Django: Redirect after HttpResponse

Tags: django, redirect, refresh, httpresponse

I am generating a report download in a view and starting the download after processing the POST data. That means the user sends a form and the download starts:

views.py

```
def export(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'export_treat' in request.POST: 
        form1 = TransExport(request.POST, instance= obj)
        if form1.is_valid():
            ... 
            ...
            response=HttpResponse(ds.xls,content_type="application/xls")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Report_Behandlungen.xls"'
            return response
```

What I need is a page refresh after the download (or a redirect).
How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: I do not understand how this helps. A simple redirect is clear to me and is not going to help here. I use the view's return already for a HttpResponse (the XLS file). I need an additional redirect.

Answer (score 3):

I would just do it in simple logic with javascript:

user clicks the link

```
/download_file_now/
```

and comes to `/file_downloaded/` where the download starts and after 3 seconds, you just redirect the page via js

```
location.replace('/another_url/');
```

to detect if the download is ready is not easy